# AngularJS -- How to explain the output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What's different between 'template' and 'templateUrl' in angularjs directive ?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <child-a-drtv></child-a-drtv>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('childADrtv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'child-A-template.html',
        //template: 'A<child-b-drtv></child-b-drtv>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('childA Controller');
        },
        link: function () {
            console.log('childA Link');
        }
    };
})

app.directive('childBDrtv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'child-B-template.html',
        //template: 'B<child-c-drtv></child-c-drtv>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('childB Controller');
        },
        link: function () {
            console.log('childB Link');
        }
    };
})

app.directive('childCDrtv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'child-C-template.html',
        //template: 'C',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('childC Controller');
        },
        link: function () {
            console.log('childC Link');
        }
    };
});
```

child-A-template.html:

```
A<child-b-drtv></child-b-drtv>
```

child-B-template.html:

```
B<child-c-drtv></child-c-drtv>
```

child-C-template.html:

```
C
```

Output:

```
childA Controller
childA Link
childB Controller
childB Link
childC Controller
childC Link
```

When you use 'template' to replace 'templateUrl', you will get different output.
app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('childADrtv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //templateUrl: 'child-A-template.html',
        template: 'A<child-b-drtv></child-b-drtv>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('childA Controller');
        },
        link: function () {
            console.log('childA Link');
        }
    };
})

app.directive('childBDrtv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //templateUrl: 'child-B-template.html',
        template: 'B<child-c-drtv></child-c-drtv>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('childB Controller');
        },
        link: function () {
            console.log('childB Link');
        }
    };
})

app.directive('childCDrtv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //templateUrl: 'child-C-template.html',
        template: 'C',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('childC Controller');
        },
        link: function () {
            console.log('childC Link');
        }
    };
});
```

Output:

```
childA Controller
childB Controller
childC Controller
childC Link
childB Link
childA Link
```

Comment: `A<child-b-drtv></child-b-drtv>` is this is what you wrote in `child-A-template.html` ?

Comment: Did you tried to run the program several time? Are you sure is it not a thread kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) you will find the followings. I think it explain your output

**templateUrl**

This is similar to template but the template is loaded from the specified URL, asynchronously.

> Because template loading is asynchronous the compiler will suspend
>   compilation of directives on that element for later when the template
>   has been resolved. In the meantime it will continue to compile and
>   link sibling and parent elements as though this element had not
>   contained any directives. The compiler does not suspend the entire
>   compilation to wait for templates to be loaded because this would
>   result in the whole app "stalling" until all templates are loaded
>   asynchronously - even in the case when only one deeply nested
>   directive has templateUrl.

Template loading is asynchronous even if the template has been preloaded into the $templateCache

So for your case when you are using templateUrl, angular calls that templateUrl asynchronously, mean while it executes its own link function.

But while you are using template, then there is no need of any asynchronous call. Angular start compiling immediately your template and going to invoke next directive controller. While it reaches last directive it return back by calling link function from C to A.